# How to check availability and length of new data through Android Volley

Tags: android, caching, android-volley

I have used Android Volley library for loading and caching of data coming from a server. The following is the simple code I used.

```
// Creating volley request queue
RequestQueue queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(getActivity());

// Creating volley request obj
JsonArrayRequest mReq = new JsonArrayRequest(url,
    new Response.Listener<JSONArray>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(JSONArray response) {
            Log.d(TAG, response.toString());
            hidePDialog();
            progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);

            // update the data fetched from server
            if(mList != null)
            {
                mList.clear();
            }

            parseVolleyResponse(response);
            // notifying list adapter about data changes
            // so that it renders the list view with updated data
            rAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            Log.d("notifyDataSetChanged", "notifyDataSetChanged");
        }
    }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            VolleyLog.d(TAG, "Error: " + error.getMessage());
            hidePDialog();
        }
    });

// Adding volley request to the queue
queue.add(mReq);
```

The loading and caching are working fine. Now, I want to display a message like "15 new data available. Tap to load." at the top of my layout whenever new data is available at server end i.e. I want to notify whenever new data is available along with its length. How can I do that? Should I use this `Entry entry = queue.getCache().get(url);` to check the difference between cache and network? Please help with the coding.

Comment: ache might be obsolete because of flags set by server (max-age, ...) So you better compare data received by volley with internally represented data. Best approach would be to let server inform you if there are new data available via GCM and then request it via Volley.

Comment: Thanks Maxxxo. you have valid points. I have seen Google+ displaying "New Posts! Touch to see them". Wondering how to achieve that. So I need to try with GCM. At least I have a clue now.